# Enumerate events/eventListeners for a WinJS object

Tags: winjs

I'm using pure WinJS for a project (No jQuery) and have run into a requirement that has me stumped.

Let's say I have a DOM element called 'bob' (although this might not necessarily be a DOM element). To attach an event listener, I would do this:

```
bob.addEventListener('click', function ()
{
  // Some code goes here
});
```

There is nothing stopping me from adding lots of event listeners to 'bob', even for the same event names (which is fine as they are just queued) - herein lies the rub!

I need to be able to enumerate the events/listeners that are attached to a given object so I can selectively replace or tweak some of them at runtime.

Any thoughts on how to acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you can, in some circumstances, enumerate attached event listeners.

If you are using the 'Events' Mixin on an object, then once you have called one of the mixed-in methods (addEventListener, removeEventListener or dispatchEvent), your target object will gain a property called _listeners (assuming it doesn't already exist).

For a practical example, here's a function that counts the number of attached event listeners for an object that uses this mixin:

```
/*
 * Counts the number of attached listeners
 */
 countListeners: function()
 {
    var count = 0;

    if (this._listeners)
    {
       var key;

       for (key in this._listeners)
       {
          if (this._listeners.hasOwnProperty(key))
          {
             count++;
          }
       }
    }

    return count;
 }
```

Hope this helps someone!

G

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to enumerate events added using addEventListener. The way you're adding the event is not recommended (at least by me :). You're using addEventListener but then using an anonymous method. If you do that then you'll never be able to remove that event because you don't have a handle to it. I would recommend creating your function and then assigning the named function (`myelement.addEventListener("event", myfunction)`). Each time you add an event to your element, just add it to a collection (an array hanging off the element itself) and then you'll have your list of events.

Comment: Hi jeremy! Fear not, I am already wise to your remove listener fears, it was just a crude example to illustrate my question :-)  So there isn't a way to access the event handler queue? :-(

Comment: You could also create a separate event list if you have a specific need, creating your own dispatcher that would allow you to control the behavior as you need. I do wonder, however, if the electro modify the handlers ‘live‘ is the best pattern.

Comment: I guess overriding the 'event' mixin is one way to go. Thanks everyone!